# stop apache gracefully at shutdown

Tags: shutdown, apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I have some ec2 instances running in AWS, which are scaled by an autoscale policy, all is fine the machines scale up and down quite well.
However one glitch we have is that when it scales down the requests being processed at (to be terminated) instances are lost in middle while the termination happens.

What I would like to do is catch the shutdown signal, and ask apache to gracefull shutdown and then let the shutdown continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it, its a sort of hack, but seems to be working for me.

When the system gets a shutdown signal, the scripts in folder /etc/rc0.d are executed, which involves scripts to shutdown all the services inclusive of Apache; in case the script takes too long to shutdown AWS will power off, I don't know how long is too long.

Anyways, so this is what I did, I edited  /etc/rc0.d/K09apache2 file

At apache_stop function
apache_stop() {

```
if $APACHE2CTL configtest > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            # if the config is ok than we just stop normaly
            #$APACHE2CTL stop 2>&1 | grep -v 'not running' >&2 || true
            echo "stopping the apache gracefully"
            $APACHE2CTL -k graceful-stop 2>&1 | grep -v 'not running' >&2 || true
            sleep 15
```

Change the abrupt stop to graceful stop and give a sleep of 15 seconds to make sure that it does die gracefully.

Update - Now Amazon ELB provides the graceful removal of instances as a feature.